# Alternating the footer on odd and even pages with memoir

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I'm using the memoir class, which has the option to directly define what should be shown on odd and even pages, seperately. I want to put the page number on the left of the left pages, and on the right of the right pages. Just like a regular book.

But somehow, it's not working. This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[danish]{varioref}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{icomma}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{billeder/}}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{color,soul}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[includeheadfoot,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\makepagestyle{standard}
\makeevenhead{standard}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{standard}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{standard}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}{}{AO, DA, NFL}
\makeoddfoot{standard}{AO, DA, NFL}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{3pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
\pagestyle{standard}

\begin{document}

\author{AO, DA, NFL}
\title{Title}
\date{2015.06.01}
\maketitle
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents*
\pagebreak

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

From the answers I've gotten so far, i've changed the argument of "oneside" in the very first line to "twoside", and it works. But as described below, now, the title page and ToC has changed. These are snapshots of oneside titlepage and ToC, and twoside twoside titlepage and ToC.

[image: Oneside, titlepage]

[image: Oneside, ToC]

[image: Twoside, titlepage]

[image: Twoside, ToC]

Comment: Hi and welcome, very good to post an example. A regular book is printed both sided, your document is specified `oneside`. Left pages are non-existent here.

Comment: In addition to Johannes' comment, under `onside`, only the `odd` layout is used, so `even` is ignored. You have to switch to `twoside` in order to get even and odd header design

Comment: @daleif I got a chat ping and was distracted. I wanted to write more.

Comment: Also watch out for chapter style pages. Pages with new chapters have their own style and will not follow your standard style (don't be surprised that the page number will be centered).

Comment: Thanks! Changing it to twosided works! However, when doing so, the title page and ToC are messed up. With onesided, they are nice and collected, but with twosided, huge linebreaks are inserted in between. On the other hand the rest of the document looks great.

Comment: Use `\newpage` not `\pagebreak`. `\pagebreak` should not be used. Under `twoside` we run under flushbottom, whereas `oneside` under under raggedbottom. So LaTeX will now try to make all pages the same height. If you then use `\pagebreak` then it attempts to fill the page vertically. `\newpage` does not. Forget you ever heard of `\pagebreak`.

Comment: @daleif Can you add a short answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B, not really as it is not particulrly clear what is being answered here

Comment: @daleif It seems to be a combination of missing `twoside` in combination with the behaviour `\pagebreak` has in `flushbottom` mode. As often, a cascade of issues :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B done

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

1. use `twoside` class option to enable left/right headers (in `oneside` only the `odd` version is used)
2. Never use `\pagebreak` unless you know what you are doing. You are probably looking for `\newpage`

Comment: mange tak! شكرا