# Need to have different arrangement of footer on odd and even pages

Tags: header-footer, templates, footer, journal

I am trying to create a template for a paper for a journal as I am the editor. I want to have footers on each page exclusing the first. The format should be :

FOOTER TEXT and Page no  - Toward the right side of the even pages
Page no  - FOOTER TEXT  - Toward the left side of the odd pages

here is the code

```
     \documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % Disable hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[left=0.79in, right=0.79in, top=0.79in, bottom=0.79in]{geometry}

% Define the first page style
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{ACF (1).png}}
  \fancyhead[L]{Journal of Asian Concrete Federation
\newline Vol. 9, No. 2, pp. XXXXXX, Dec. 2023
\newline ISSN 2465-7964 / eISSN 2465-7972
\newline DOI http://XXXXXX}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

% Define the regular page style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[RO]{\footnotesize\textit{Journal of Asian Concrete Federation, Vol. 8, No. 1, Jun. 2022} \quad \thepage}

\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage \quad \footnotesize\textit{Journal of Asian Concrete Federation, Vol. 8, No. 1, Jun. 2022}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Apply the regular page style


% Redefine the abstract environment to hide the "Abstract" title
\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\small
   \list{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0in}% <-- Adjust this value as needed
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
   }%
   \item\relax}
  {\endlist}

\title{\textbf{Finite element analysis of steel-concrete composite connection with prefabricated permanent steel form}}
\author{Hyunjin Ju \and Deuckhang Lee* \and Dong-Uk Choi}
\date{{\small Received: November 11, 2021; Accepted: March 18, 2022; Published online: June 30, 2022}}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{firstpage} % Apply the firstpage style after \maketitle


\begin{abstract}

\noindent \normalsize \textbf{Abstract:} 
\end{abstract}

\vspace{10pt} % Adjust the vertical space as needed
\noindent \textbf{Keywords:} Composite beam, Beam-column connection, Permanent steel plate, Finite element analysis, Cyclic loading test.
\vspace{20pt}
]
% Two-column layout starts here
% Left column content (Author Information)

{\noindent{\small\textbf{*Corresponding author Deuckhang Lee} is an associate Professor at Department of Architectural Engineering, Chungbuk National University, South Korea. E-mail: dk@cbnu.ac.kr
\vspace{6pt}
\newline\textbf{Hyunjin Ju} is an Assistant Professor at School of Architecture and Design Convergence, Hankyong National University, South Korea. E-mail: hju@hknu.ac.kr
\vspace{6pt}
\newline\textbf{Dong-Uk Choi} is Professor School at School of Architecture and Design Convergence, Hankyong National University, South Korea. E-mail: choidu@hknu.ac.kr}}
]

% Right column content (Introduction)
% Use \newpage to ensure the introduction starts in the right column
\newpage

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}


\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture1.png} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}


\section{Experiment Scheme}\label{sec2}
\subsection{Specimens}


\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.a.png}
  \caption{Composite beam-column connection with prefabricated permanent steel form}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-1}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.b.png}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-1}
\end{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.c.jpg}
    \caption{Subfigure (c)}
    \label{fig:wide-figure-c}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
    \end{figure*}

% For the individual wide figures
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.a.png}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.b.png}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-2}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.c.png}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-3}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.d.jpg}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-4}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.e.jpg}
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure-5}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.b.png} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.c.png} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.d.jpg} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.e.jpg} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}

\subsection{Test set-up}

\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4.png} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[t] % Use [t] to place the figure at the top of the page
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5.png} % Replace with your image file
  \caption{This is a wide figure that spans both columns.}
  \label{fig:wide-figure}
\end{figure*}

\section{Finite element simulation}
\subsection{Modeling}

\subsection{Materials assigned}


\subsection{Interaction}




\end{document}
```

Comment: The default of `article` is `oneside`. In single-sided mode LaTeX does not distinguish odd and even pages. All pages are odd. So to have odd and even pages, you need at least class option `twoside`.

Comment: BTW: It would be useful to be able to reproduce your problem without changing or adding anything. So please extend your code to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) not only starting with `\documentclass`, but also containing a body from `\begin{document}` down to `\end{document}` with some code between to reproduce your problem. You can, e.g., use [package `mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) to generate dummy content.

Comment: BTW: You should also read: [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/277964)

Comment: Please don't change the question after you have got relevant answers and (especially) after you've accepted one as answering your question. If you have a further question, ask a new question and link to this one for context, if appropriate. I've rolled back your changes so the answer you accepted answers the question asked. Obviously you're free to undo this, but the site follows a Q&A format and it matters that answers match questions. Aside from anything else, what will you do if somebody new answers your new question? You cannot accept both.

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` too late. It should be loaded last except for anything you know needs to be loaded afterwards. If this is for authors, you should also specify the paper size because different users may have TeX configured with different defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `twoside` class option to enable left/right headers (in `oneside` only the `odd` version is used).

Note from [the answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238494/alternating-the-footer-on-odd-and-even-pages-with-memoir/284148#284148): require the authors to avoid using `\pagebreak` in their submission unless they know what they are doing, and to prefer `\newpage`.

Comment: Thanks this saves a ton of work for me.